# Cannot install ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot my old PC (an Acer extensa e264) currently running Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.

However, when I choose to install alongside Windows and continue, the installation CD is ejected and the screen remains black.

I have tried using different installation CDs and USB sticks and I've also tried Ubuntu Gnome 14.10.

How can I resolve this issue?

UPDATE: here is the link for the gParted screenshot and when 1 try to install Ubuntu on a partition

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bs3FBGR.png]

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jGnd6Z5.png]

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same probleme and I successed to solve this issue. The probleme is that your partition are certainly in MBR but, and I don't now how to explain clearly, it rest some GTP. Also try to do this command in the terminal:

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
```

It will show that GTP is present or exist.

After, do:

```
sudo fixparts /dev/sda
```

I hope I can help you.

Comment: i tried but its not working 
here are screenshot form the first and second commands

http://i.imgur.com/sTV9ETx.png
http://i.imgur.com/IPGaSVl.png

Comment: Actually there's no GPT present, also I haven't any idea of what can cause this issue ...